# mypy explicit type hint in quotes still gives not defined error

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to do the following thing:

```
self.sender = None # type: 'Node'
```

I can't import Node because I would get an cycle. So I write it in quotes like mentioned here
http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#import-cycles
But I still get the following error

```
error: Name 'Node' is not defined
```

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Short answer, you need to include the module name of the class, and you need to import that module within some unreachable code, like this:

```
if False:
    # for forward-reference type-checking:
    import mymodule

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sender = None  # type: mymodule.Node
```

In order to understand why this is required (and why it works), you must first realize that mypy is doing *static* code analysis.  That means it's not importing your modules, it's parsing and analyzing text read from your module files.

When the module above is imported, the `import mymodule` line will never run and will therefore avoid your cyclical import, but it is still available for mypy to parse.  This is how mypy is able to resolve the reference to `mymodule.Node` during analysis.

For the sake of completeness, I should mention that it is not required that you use the module name, you can use any name that won't cause a conflict during parsing:

```
if False:
    from mymodule import Node

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sender = None  # type: Node
```

Also note that you do not need to use quotes around type names that appear in comments.  That is only necessary when the type annotation appears directly in a python object.  Here are some scenarios where that might happen:

```
from typing import Optional, NamedTuple
if False:
    from mymodule import Node

NodeInfo = NamedTuple('NodeInfo', [('node', 'Node'), ('info', dict)])

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, sender: Optional['Node'] = None):
        self.sender = sender
```